# How to retrieve Image from MS SQL database varbinary(max) to Bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, bitmap, base64

i want to retrieve an Image from MS SQL database. In database its stored as type varbinary(max), but in Android i need to convert it to Bitmap.

But when I run my code it always throws `IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64`

In the column of the database its stored like this:
`0x5B42403965393862316230` but in the application it always returns like this `[B@9ea047a8`.

Here is the code to save the image (this runs fine):

```
public User saveProfilPicture(User user){
        Connection con = DBConnection.connection();
        try {

            Bitmap captureImage = user.getProfilImage();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            captureImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE dbo.[User] 
SET profilImage = (CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '"+ bytes +"')) WHERE userID = " + user.getUserID()+";");
            update.executeUpdate();
            user.setCreateStatus(true);

        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            user.setCreateStatus(false);
        }


        return user;
    }
```

Here is the code to retrieve the image (there is the error):

```
public User findProfilPicture(User user)  {
        Connection con = DBConnection.connection();
        try{
            PreparedStatement get = con.prepareStatement("SELECT  CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 
[profilImage]) AS profilImage FROM dbo.[User] WHERE userID =" + user.getUserID() +";");
            System.out.println(get.toString());
            ResultSet rs = get.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {

                byte[] bytesResult = rs.getBytes("profilImage");
                byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(String.valueOf(bytesResult), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0, bytes.length);

                user.setProfilImage(bitmap);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return user;
    }
```

Where is the mistake? Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: You don't use Base64 to encode the image bytes when storing them in the database so why are you trying to use Base64 to decode them?

Comment: Also, why use prepared statements when you don't use parameters with them? e.g.: when saving try: `PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE dbo.[User] SET profilImage=? WHERE userID=?"); update.setBytes(1, bytes); update.setInt(2, user.getUserID());` When saving JPEG images successfully the varbinary blob in SQL Server should start with 0xFFD8FF.